# How to gracefully reload a spawn-fcgi script for nginx

Tags: nginx, spawn-fcgi

My stack is nginx that runs python web.py fast-cgi scripts using spawn-fcgi.  I am using runit to keep the process alive as a Daemon.  I am using unix sockets fior the spawed-fcgi.

The below is my runit script called myserver in /etc/sv/myserver with the run file in /etc/sv/myserver/run.

```
exec spawn-fcgi -n -d /home/ubuntu/Servers/rtbTest/ -s /tmp/nginx9002.socket -u www-data -f /home/ubuntu/Servers/rtbTest/index.py >> /var/log/mylog.sys.log 2>&1
```

I need to push changes to the sripts to the production servers.  I use paramiko to ssh into the box and update the index.py script.

My question is this, how do I gracefully reload the index.py using best practice to update to the new code.

Do I use:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Do I restart the the runit script:
    sudo sv start myserver

Or do I use both:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
sudo sv start myserver
```

Or none of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to re-start the process that's loaded your Python script. This is spawn-cgi and not nginx itself. nginx only communicates with spawn-cgi via the Unix socket and will happily re-connect if the connection is lost due to a restart of the spawn-cgi process.

Therefore I'd suggest a simple `sudo sv restart myserver`. No need to re-start/re-load nginx itself.